# Adding column filter for bootstrap table (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web, angularjs-filter

I am wondering if there is an easy way to add the simple filter options (similar to excel with multiselect option) for each column in a bootstrap table.

I have searched enough on google, but couldn't find a single answer for same.

[image]

When a user will click this filter icon, a dropdown should appear which multiselect option.

Can anyone give me some pointers on this.

Here is my sample plunkr. Please let me know if anyone need any more information.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XXaSmg7ZzcPJbB70mIpZ?p=preview

```
<td class="no-wrap-text">Status
                &nbsp;<a href="">
                <i class="fa fa-filter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td>Severity&nbsp;
  </td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How bootstrap-table to use search and filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838297/how-bootstrap-table-to-use-search-and-filter)

Comment: I m looking for angularjs solution.. I will prefer that as my last option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin written specifically for bootstrap:
http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/